# Is my $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I have written the complete $\varepsilon-\delta$a proof for $\lim_{x \to 0} x^3 + 1 = 1$, and have included rough work. Can someone please verify whether my proof is correct? Thanks in advance.

[image: I have written the proof by hand here]

Comment: Good Grief! Your proof is excellent!  I am especially impressed how you were about to separate what is to be shown and the derivation of what you would need to show it without confusing with the proof itself.

Comment: Oh.  I did miss the $-1 < x < 1\implies 1 < x^2 < 1$.  Clearly not true (in fact it's impossible).  As $-1 < 0$ is doesn't follow that $-1 < x \implies (-1)^2 < x^2$.  But $-1< x< 1 \implies 0\le |x|< 1 \implies |x|^2 < 1$ and $x^2 = |x^2|$ so $x^2 < 1$.

Comment: @fleablood luckily it was in the part deliberately marked 'rough work' :)

Comment: @CalvinKhor  which is probably why I missed it.

Comment: @fleablood So would it be correct to write Hence, $-1 < x < 1$, and $|x^2| < 1$ in the third line of the proof?

Comment: Yes.  I think $-1 < x < 1\implies x^2 < 1$  would be enough.  If you have to justify why you could either point out $0\le |x|<1$ so $|x|^2=x^2 < 1$ or $-1<x < 0\implies x^2 < (-1)^2=1$ and $0\le x < 1\implies x^2 < 1^2 =1$.  But this is so very basic and unimportant and there is stuff so more important, I cant say any instructor would have issue with concluding $-1< x < 1\implies x^2 < 1$ without question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is basically correct, but halfway through you write $1 < x^2 < 1$ which is certainly not true, but fortunately also not necessary.